# How to handle rails 3 model relationships at view and controller level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, user-interface

I have a project going on right now that is really big data model wise. I am trying to figure out the best way to handle inter-model relationships.

For the sake of brevity:

```
Car
  has_many :passengers
  has_many :items
```

or

```
Team
  has_one :head_coach
  has_many :coaches
  has_many :players
  belongs_to :owner
```

So from the show page I would see who is in the car and what items are in the car. I have some co-workers who think we should have a controller action called `manage` where they would click a link on the show page to manage the relationship between the other models

So the `Team` controller would have this

```
class TeamController < ApplicationController
  # ... magic ...
  def manage_players
     @signed_players = Player.signed_players
     @free_agents    = Player.free_agents
  end
end
```

The `manage_players` view would just have links to the actual RESTful actions on the appropriate controller to remove relationships etc...

Anyone have thoughts on how this should be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an overly complicated approach, and the good news is, it's way simpler than you think.

Save yourself some trouble. The quick answer to your question is to use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources): you can have a single form that handles the `Car` and all the associated passengers/items, or the `Team` and its coach, players, etc.

The action/view you're describing would just be the `edit` action on the `Car`/`Team`. The `manage` action name is a nice idea and all, but the action you're really taking is an edit (nothing special, by what you're describing), so why confuse what's going on when the default is to call it `edit`?

If you want a live example of something that takes advantage of nested routes, check out [rpglogger.com](http://rpglogger.com) (it's my site). When you play around with it, notice the routes/URLs in the address bar.

It's also [open source](https://github.com/normalocity/rpglogger). Specifically relevant to your question is:

- see the [routes.rb file](https://github.com/normalocity/rpglogger/blob/master/config/routes.rb), and note how I define resources on `sections` twice - this actually gives me two different versions of the routes - one that's scoped to the LogBook, and one that's scoped to the objects in a section
- see the [world_object_form.haml](https://github.com/normalocity/rpglogger/blob/master/app/views/world_objects/world_object_form.haml) ([haml](http://haml-lang.com/) also rocks, FYI), which is both my `new` and `edit` form - yet it's short, rather uncomplicated, and pretty easy to read/undestand given what it does.

Comment: I know about nested resources. I just wanted an idea of how others approached this problem. I've done most of this stuff using Backbone.js and other AJAX stuff where I wouldn't have to worry so much about what page I am on. But with our first prototype we just wanted it to work using simple HTTP requests before we ramped up into AJAX

Comment: Well, okay - but one of the major reasons that Rails saves you time is when you can follow convention over configuration - not trying to just repeat the mantra - I really does save you having to re-decide all those architectural choices. What you're describing is a perfect fit for those, not some "almost" fit situation.